# Is there a function to escape all regex-relevant characters?

Tags: swift, regex, nsregularexpression

The regex I'm using in my application is a combination of user-input and code. Because I don't want to restrict the user I would like to escape all regex-relevant characters like "+", brackets , slashes etc. from the entry.
Is there a function for that or at least an easy way to get all those characters in an array so that I can do something like this:

```
for regexChar in regexCharacterArray{
    myCombinedRegex = myCombinedRegex.replaceOccurences(of: regexChar, with: "\\" + regexChar)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is [`NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression/1408386-escapedpattern):

> Returns a string by adding backslash escapes as necessary to protect any characters that would match as pattern metacharacters.

Example:

```
let escaped = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: "[*]+")
print(escaped) // \[\*]\+
```

Comment: so I would insert the string i would like to have the regex-characters escaped in as the `for:`-value ?

Comment: @LarsGvB: Yes, exactly.

Comment: I expected the output to be `\[\*\]\+` (note the back slash before `]`)

Comment: @Soc: No, you don't have to escape a closing square bracket. It has no special meaning if it does not follow an (unescaped) opening square bracket.

Comment: Understood. In my use case I was trying to use the escaped expression inside square brackets i.e. `"[\(escaped)]"`. I ended up having to replace `]` with `\]` on the escaped sequence for this to work.